# UITableView reloadData doesnt reload the table but UITableView reloadSections work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView embedded inside a parent UIView. I have a CustomUITableViewController class set as delegate and datasource for the tableview.
After a certain background operation, I get an updated array of objects to be displayed in the tableview.

When I update the datasource array and call tableview.reloadData method, the tableview doesn't refresh. It only refreshes if I scroll the tableview.

However, if I call the API as follows:

tableview.beginUpdates -> tableview.reloadSections -> tableview.endUpdates,

it works perfectly and immediately reloads the table.
The problem is that depending on the new data, I have to add a new section, or remove an old section from the tableview.

Hence I am not able to use the reloadSections API.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"tempCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    [cell initializeWithModel:modelsToShow[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
-(void) showModelsInList:(NSMutableArray*) models {
    [modelsToShow removeAllObjects];
    [modelsToShow addObjectsFromArray:models];
    [self setupDataForList];
    [self reloadTable];
}

-(void) reloadTable {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSMutableIndexSet* index = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
    [index addIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:index withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
   //[self.tableView reloadData]
}
```

The showModelsInList method is invoked from the other class, in the main thread itself.

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` from the main thread (queue)?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried the reloadData directly as well as the performSelectorOnMainThread API. Both of them didnt work.

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndex` implementation and where you call `reloadData`.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code snippet.

Comment: What you've posted so far looks good. Please show `initializeWithModel`. I'm looking to see what changes you're making to the cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Adding/removing/rearranging views from a queued cell don't always update right away and can cause the issue you describe. Instead, use a different cell prototype for each layout, and set the identifier accordingly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Or to test the theory, just for testing, don't reuse cells (don't call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Okay. Looks like its the issue with initializeWithModel. When I dont dequeue cells its working as expected. But when I dequeue, it doesnt refresh. There is quite an amount of code in the intializeWithModel method, where the labels, icons etc are all initialized and constraints are added.

Comment: Have you implemented `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell? If you don't clear things there it can happen that it shows old data. I suppose you have made sure that `setNeedsDisplay` is called after updating the view in the cell.

Comment: No. I have not implemented `prepareForReuse`. Although why the different behaviour for reloadData and reloadSections?

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to initialize table view cells is to register the cell class (or nib, if the cell is defined in its own nib).  `viewDidLoad` is a good time to do this...

```
// if the cell is a prototype defined in the nib containing the table view, or if
// the cell is built in code in its init method
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tempCell"];

// or, if the cell is defined in its own nib
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"your cell's nib name goes here" bundle:nil];
[_tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tempCell"];
```

In either case above, the cell must have it's "tempCell" identifier initialized in IB or in code.  Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, dequeue the cell using the method...

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tempCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

No further check is required to see `if (cell == nil)`.  This version of dequeue will just work (or crash, if something's not setup correctly).

Comment: If you create the prototype in the nib (storyboard), you don't need to register the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, technically, it's a bug, but the truth is that, though it's not documented, you shouldn't be recreating subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when reusing cells.

Create the cells with all needed subviews at design time in Interface Builder. Changing their positions, sizes, and other properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is okay.

If your cells have different subviews, each cell "type" should be its own class. Create a different prototype cell class with a different identifier for each, and simply use that identifier when you dequeue the cell. That way, you have the proper cell class in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

To reference additional properties (subviews) from your view controller, simply create class files for each cell type (derived from UITableViewCell). Assign it to the prototype UITableViewCell in IB, drag the views to the .h file to create outlets like you do for a view controller, then import that class in your view controller.

So, you might end up with code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (whatever) {
       MyBasicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"basicCell"];
       cell.specialLabel.Text = ...
       return cell;
    } else {
       MyOtherCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"otherCell"];
       cell.otherLabel.Text = ...
       return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your advice and redid all the subviews in a brand new cell using XIBs. The previous one was legacy code, and nothing worked to fix the problem. It working fine now. Thanks!